# How to get a list of URLs from an defined bookmark's folder in Safari

Tags: terminal, safari, applescript, command-line, bookmarks

Have many bookmarks in the Safari's Favorites. Let say, have an folder called `perl` and it contains many links and also subforlders with links, like in the screenshot:

[image]

Need to extract all bookmarked links from the `perl` folder and it's subfolders **using ONLY Terminal's command line**. E.g. want run some command in the Terminal, like:

```
get_my_bookmarks perl
```

and the result will be a list of URLs.

It is possible to achieve this with applescrit, e.g. with

```
 osascript -e '... some applescript voodoo ...'
```

or by using some tool and extracting the wanted links info from the binary `~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist`, e.g. the following

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c Print ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist
```

dumps the whole plist (xml) - but how to easily extract only URLs from one defined bookmark-folder? Any idea for some simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling and learning [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expressions, the solution is really simple:

The following shell script - let say its name is `dump_bookmarks.sh`,

```
#!/bin/bash
for foldername
do
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -x -c Print ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist | \
    xmlstarlet sel --net -t -v "//key[.='Title']/following-sibling::string[.='$foldername']/parent::node()//key[.='URLString']/following-sibling::string[1]"
    echo    #print an newline after the last entry
done
```

and using it as

```
./print_bookmarks.sh perl  #argument is the bookmark-folder name
```

will print a list of bookmarked URLs, like for the above screenshot will print:

```
https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny
http://perlmaven.com/perl-based-open-source-products
http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-standard-preamble.html
https://acidcycles.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/implementing-factories-in-perl/
http://gcstar.softonic.com/
http://steffen-wendzel.blogspot.de/p/blog-page_24.html
http://continuity.tlt42.org/
```

For the script you need install the `xmlstarlet` command, for example using [Macports](https://www.macports.org)

```
sudo port install xmlstarlet
```